# Does browser create separate http connection for each request(I mean different host. Eg:google.com, yahoo.com).?

Tags: http

When we browse different website from the same browser, Does it create separate http connection for each

Comment: This is largely dependent on the browser implementation.  There's probably a global connection pool with limits on how many connections per host.

Comment: Well if it connects to different hosts it obviously has to create different connections.

Comment: http connections are asynchronous. So the number of http connections allowed per host is probably very high. It's not like direct database connections that are required to be kept open and their session active before they can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch detailed information about connections using wireshark which you can download here: http://www.wireshark.org/download.html